# NOT EXISTS with INNER JOIN not returning the expected result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have temporary table `#Inserts` where I collect records on which eventually I will perform `INSERT` at some point. Before doing that I need to filter out some of the data. The first query is using `NOT EXISTS` and it doesn't return the correct results:

```
  SELECT I.UnitId 
  FROM #Inserts AS I 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1  
    from   #Inserts AS INS  
    INNER JOIN Organisation AS O 
        ON INS.OrganisationId = O.OrganisationId
        AND INS.UnitId = O.UnitId
    )
```

However if do the following:

```
  DELETE INS FROM #Inserts AS INS   
  INNER JOIN Organisation AS O
        ON INS.OrganisationId = O.OrganisationId
        AND INS.UnitId = O.UnitId
```

then if i `SELECT * FROM #Inserts` I can see the the records are filtered as I've been expected. What am I doing wrong with the `NOT EXISTS` and how can I get the same behavior as that with `DELETE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you intend a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT I.UnitId 
FROM #Inserts I 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1  
                  FROM Organisation AS O 
                  WHERE I.OrganisationId = O.OrganisationId AND I.UnitId = O.UnitId
                 );
```

Your version is running an independent subquery.  If any rows are returned, then `NOT EXISTS` returns false.

Comment: Yeap, it seems that this is exactly what I needed. Thanks!